# regular expression python - catch filenames

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to search for a specific pattern to grab only those files which align with the pattern in a given folder.
I need some assistance to develop a regular expression that matches two patterns - i can't seem to find one that will match both.
This is the original regular expression i used:

```
r"^([a-zA-Z]+)__?(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)\.xlsx"
```

The reason for this search pattern, is that I then extract the name, date (dd-mm-yy) and full-file name into five variables, this allows me to extract the date included in the full-file name which refers to the input date of the file.

```
for name, day, month, year, fullfilename in files
```

Now I am trying the following:

```
files = []
for f in os.listdir(drive):
    match = re.search(r"^([a-zA-Z-]+)__?(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).xlsx$",f)
    if match:
        files.append(match.groups() + (f,))
```

Sample filenames:

```
filename_19.01.17.xlsx
filename__04.01.17.xlsx
AB_TEST_DATA-OUTER_13.02.17.xlsx
```

So the extraction should be the following:

```
filename, 19, 01, 17, filename_19.01.17.xlsx
```

Also tried the following:

```
r"^(([a-zA-Z-]+)(__?)){1,3}(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).xlsx"
```

Is it possible to have one pattern to match both all files? Or should I split them into two patterns?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but what's wrong with a plain `".*\.xlsx"`? Are there any other xlsx files in that directory that you don't want?

Comment: @Bahrom yes there are,which i do not want to match

Answer (score 1):

The pattern here seems to be as:

Firstly, some alphabets, followed by one or more under-scores, the a date in format of xx.xx.xx and the `.xlsx` format at the end, which can be translated to regex as:

```
\S+_+(\d+.){3}\.xlsx
```

> Break-Up:
>
> \S+ - matches any non-whitespace character, one or multiple
>   times.
>
> _+  - matches under-score character one or multiple times.
>
> (\d+.){3} - Number in format of xx.xx.xx.
>
> .xlsx - matches the extension of file.

Comment: this works as a full-match, great! but I change the specifics, please see above. I essentially want to have groups.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
^.+__?(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.xlsx$
```

---

Broken down this means:

```
^         # start of the string
.+        # anything up to the end, giving up as needed
__?       # one or two underscores
(\d{2})\. # exactly two digits, followed by a dot
(\d{2})\.
(\d{2})\.
xlsx      # "xlsx" literally
$         # the end
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wu96UP/2). Additionally, have a look at [**`glob()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).